# Reading image from private storage android

Tags: android, image, bitmap, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

I have stored some image in the device private storage like:

```
    InputStream inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = openFileOutput("someImage.jpeg", cont.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int read = 0;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];
    while((read = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
    fileOutputStream.close();
    inputStream.close();
```

Then I want to read that image and store it as bitmap to show it to the user, I don't know what to do to accomplish this! I want to read the image again from the private storage, then convert it to bitmap.
any experience?

Comment: That might not be a good idea as the user can remove that image. Why do you want that exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need here is [`BitmapFactory.decodeStream(String name)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeStream(java.io.InputStream)).

First, get an inputstream:

```
InputStream input = openFileInput("someImage.jpeg");
```

Next, use that to get a bitmap:

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
```

Don't forget to close your inputstream afterwards!